# Como buscar un numero dentro de un archivo en C

Tags: c, archivo

Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario digite un número, para después ese número compararlo con cualquier número que este guardado en un archivo previamente llenado; pero no se cómo se realiza eso ya que tengo una mezcla de caracteres y números, por lo cual no se como compararlo exactamente con un número entero.

Esto es lo que esta guardado dentro del archivo:

```
Nombre: Torivio Fernandez Gonzales ID: 101 Correo Electronico:
tidivida@gmil.com Telefono: 81818-80856 Especialidad: Todo Tarifa: 900
Nombre: Pablito Fernandez ID: 102 Correo Electronico:
ubdqiebdq@gmail.com Telefono: 81818-80856 Especialidad: Cardiologia
Tarifa: 123 Nombre: Alejandro Martinez ID: 103 Correo Electronico:
Alednqiub@gmail.com Telefono: 81818-80856 Especialidad: Pediatria
Tarifa: 100 Nombre: uqibqidb ID: 102 Correo Electronico: idbqiubdq
Telefono: 82321 Especialidad: uwhb Tarifa: 90 Nombre: qdbiqwbdiqu ID:
104 Correo Electronico: iqbdwquwbdoqos Telefono: 8181880856
Especialidad: qodh Tarifa: „
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[3]={101};


    FILE * doctores = fopen("Doctores.txt", "r+");
    if(doctores==NULL)
    {
        printf("error en la creacion del archivo\n");
    }

    char temp[512];
    while(fgets(temp, 512, doctores) != NULL) {
            if((strstr(temp, a) != NULL)) {
                printf("ID ya asignado.");
            }
    }
    fclose(doctores);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría que luego de obtener el número del usuario realices un typecasting para convertirlo en una cadena de caracteres (claro, a no ser que guardes el número en un arreglo de caracteres).
Luego, abres el archivo y realizas lo siguiente:

`

```
char a;

While((fread(&a,sizeof(char),1,fp))!=0) //Lee los caracteres del archivo uno a uno:
{
//Comparacion de caracteres

if(a=='1'){ // Por ejemplo, quieres encontrar un 1.
    //Codigo...
}
}
```

`

Verifica la sintaxis y hazme saber si no funciona para poder mejorarlo.

EDITO: Agrego un código funcional:

```
char temp[512]; 
while(fgets(temp, 512, doctores) != NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) { // str es la cadena de caracteres que deseas buscar en el archivo
            printf("ID ya asignado.");
        }
}
```

EDITO: Agrego código sin errores.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[3]={101};


    FILE * doctores = fopen("Doctores.txt", "r+");
    if(doctores==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error en la lectura del archivo\n");
    }

    char temp[512];
    if (fgets(temp, 512, doctores) != NULL){
    if((strstr(temp, a) != NULL)) {
        printf("ID ya asignado.");
        printf("\n");
    } else{
        printf("ID no asignado.");
    }
}
    fclose(doctores);
}
```

Comment: `char a;
 
 
 FILE * doctores = fopen("Doctores.txt", "r+");  
 if(doctores==NULL)
 {
  printf("error en la creacion del archivo\n");
 }
 While((fread(&a,sizeof(char),1,doctores))!=0)
 {
  if(a =='101')
  {
   printf("ID Ya asigndado\n");
  }
 }
 fclose(doctores);`

Comment: Ese es el codigo que utilice dice que me falta un ";" (la verdad no lo encuentro" y un "[Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]" no se si tenga algo que ver.

Comment: Lo mejor es que edites tu respuesta original y agregues allí el código porque es prácticamente imposible detectar el error que mencionas.

Comment: Agregue el codigo a la sintaxis de mi pregunta (una disculpa, no manejo muy bien la plataforma).

Comment: Tranquilo.
Me parece que el error es debido a que estás tratando de comparar un número de un caracter con uno de tres...
Puedes mostrarme el error que te arroja el compilador?
Además, te recomiendo que crees otro archivo y escribas números random e intentes utilizar el método que te mostré.

Comment: 13 2 [Error] expected ';' before '{' token

Comment: 14 10        [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Comment: Son los 2 errores que envia el complilador, en si quiero comparar numeros con mas de 3 digitos

Comment: Revisa el nuevo código que agregué. Me comentas.

Comment: En `if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {` ¿Que debo colocar?, ya que me dice que "str" no esta declarada y tambien me marca el error "[Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in".

Comment: Cometí un error, la cadena de caracteres que vas a buscar es precisamente str.

Comment: Ya me compilo sin errores, lo ejecute y me imprime varias veces ID ya asignado (Si se encontraba adentro del archivo el numero que busque, pero me lo imprimio repetidas veces) no se si eso sea un erro

Comment: Volvi a buscar otro numero y me imprime lo mismo, varias veces ID ya encontrado cuando hora si el numero no esta dentro del archivo

Comment: Me parece bastante raro... Puedes copiar el código completo en tu pregunta original?

Comment: Ya lo he agregado.

Comment: Vale, ya me está funcionando, sucede que debía utilizar un if en lugar de un while porque lo que este último estaba haciendo es ver cuántas veces se repetía ese número y no de la mejor manera. Me disculpo por ello. Coméntame si ahora sí funciona.

Comment: Perdon por la tardanza, me funciona correctamente, muchas gracias, disculpe la pregunta, ¿este codigo sirve para cualquier cantidad de digitos verdad?

Comment: Sí, siempre y cuando cambies la cantidad de caracteres.